# how to modify peter norvig spell checker to get more number of suggestions per word

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, spell-checking

I tried the peter norvig code for spellchecker on http://norvig.com/spell-correct.html
but how do i modify it to get more number of suggestions instead of just 1 correct spelling

```
import re
from collections import Counter

def words(text):
     return re.findall(r'\w+', text.lower())

WORDS = Counter(words(open('big.txt').read()))

def P(word, N=sum(WORDS.values())): 
    "Probability of `word`."
    return WORDS[word] / N

def correction(word): 
    "Most probable spelling correction for word."
    return max(candidates(word), key=P)

def candidates(word): 
    "Generate possible spelling corrections for word."
    return (known([word]) or known(edits1(word)) or known(edits2(word)) or 
           [word])

def known(words): 
    "The subset of `words` that appear in the dictionary of WORDS."
    return set(w for w in words if w in WORDS)

def edits1(word):
    "All edits that are one edit away from `word`."
    letters    = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    splits     = [(word[:i], word[i:])    for i in range(len(word) + 1)]
    deletes    = [L + R[1:]               for L, R in splits if R]
    transposes = [L + R[1] + R[0] + R[2:] for L, R in splits if len(R)>1]
    replaces   = [L + c + R[1:]           for L, R in splits if R for c in 
                  letters]
    inserts    = [L + c + R               for L, R in splits for c in 
    letters]
    return set(deletes + transposes + replaces + inserts)

def edits2(word): 
    "All edits that are two edits away from `word`."
    return (e2 for e1 in edits1(word) for e2 in edits1(e1))import re
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `candidates` function.

It gives you

- the original word if it is correct already
- otherwise, all known words with an edit distance of 1 to the original word
- if there is no candidate with distance 1, then all candidates with distance 2
- if there was nothing in the previous case, then the original word

If candidates are found in case 2 or 3, then the returned set may contain more than one suggestion.

If the original word is returned, however, you don't know if it's the case because it's correct (case 1), or because there are no close candidates (case 4).

### However,

this approach (the way how `edits1()` is implemented) is brute force, and it's really inefficient for long words, and it gets worse if you add more characters (eg. for supporting other languages). Consider something like [simstring](http://www.chokkan.org/software/simstring/) for efficiently retrieving words with similar spelling in a large collection.

Comment: >>> import simstring
    >>> db = simstring.reader('web1tuni/web1tuni.db')
    >>> db.measure = simstring.cosine
    >>> db.threshold = 0.9
    >>> db.retrieve('approximate')
    ('approximat', 'pproximate', 'approximate', 'approximated', 
    'approximatel', 'appr
    oximates', 'approximatey', 'anapproximate', 'approximatelt', 
    'approximately', 're
    approximate', 'toapproximate')
why does it show these words which are incorrect according to dictionary
I also tried pyenchant library for spell check suggestions but it also similarly shows suggestions which have no meaning

Comment: Because web1tuni is not a dictionary, but a collection of words found on the Internet. I'm not sure why it contains bigrams, as the name suggests it should only consist of unigrams.

Comment: is there anyway i could avoid those wrong word suggestions ?
i have tried many english words in text files but many of them have words which are wrong .
while using pyenchant library i used the officially given en_US dictionary but still it gives suggestions for helo with some wrong words like 'he lo'
['helo']  
['hole', 'hello', 'helot', 'halo', 'hero', 'hell', 'held', 'helm', 'help', 'he lo']  
['grp']  
['gr', 'gorp', 'grip', 'gap', 'gyp', 'gr p']

Comment: If you accept "gr" as an abbreviation (and single letters likewise), then each of the suggestions you list are correct English words (look them up in a [dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gorp) if you don't believe me). If you want to find the most *likely* candidates, you could, for instance, consider at unigram (or n-gram) frequencies.